# Creating a filter that will iterate the condition dynamically

Tags: javascript

I want to be able to filter a list of users by a list of roles a user may have.

A demonstration of the behaviour I am trying to create. This code creates the results I am expecting but obviously isn't very practical when dealing with an undetermined number of selected filters.

```js
const users = result.data.filter(({roles}) => {
      switch (selections.length) {
        case 1:
          return roles.find((role) => role.id === filter[0]); 
        case 2:
          return (
            roles.find(({id}) => id === filter[0]) &&
            roles.find(({id}) => id === filter[1])
          );
        case 3:
          return (
            roles.find(({id}) => id === filter[0]) &&
            roles.find(({id}) => id === filter[1]) &&
            roles.find(({id}) => id === filter[2])
          );
        case 4:
          return (
            roles.find(({id}) => id === filter[0]) &&
            roles.find(({id}) => id === filter[1]) &&
            roles.find(({id}) => id === filter[2]) &&
            roles.find(({id}) => id === filter[4])
          );
        default:
          return true; //If there are no items in Select return all users.
      }
    });
```

Any help is appreciated.

Edit - restructured users, roles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the number of filters you need to search through is connected to the length of the selections, then you could use a simple loop to iterate each filter, like so:

```js
const users = result.data.filter(({roles}) => {
  if (selections.length < 1) return true;

  for (let i = 0; i < selections.length; i++) {
    if (!roles.find(({id}) => id === filter[i])) {
      return false;
    }
  }

  return true;
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I just tested and this works perfectly!